# OpenGL Transparent Background

Tags: opengl-es, min3d

Background not transparent
[image: Background not transoparent]

Using `setZOrderOnTop(true)` the background will be transparent but the 3d object covered all the views
[image: sample2]

how can i get openGL Transparent that the views are not cover by the object.

Any Ideas about OpenGL Thanks.

Im already used: glClearColor. bat it doesnt work the background will change into black color.

Comment: Up Up UP UP UP Up

Comment: Up Up Up Up Up UP